# How to find xml.xsd in Tomcat 9

Tags: xml, eclipse, tomcat, xsd

I'm following the Java EE Tutorial 2021 by Derek Banas and have run into a problem.
Starting Tomcat 9 server gives long console output in red but I can't find any specific error listed.
The final line is INFO: Server startup in [555] milliseconds.
I do have an error in the Tomcat web-xml file that I do not know how to fix.

"Multiple annotations found at this line:
- There is '1' error in 'javaee_7.xsd'.
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'platform:/plugin/org.eclipse.xsd/cache/www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd', because 1) could not
find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not xsd:schema."

Comment: Sounds like a variation of https://github.com/eclipse/lemminx/issues/1042 .

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to successfully complete the tutorial even with the tomcat web-xml file error. Not sure why everything works, but I'm glad it does.